# The $ of ```t.test(Boston$medv)``` causes some problem in Jupyter markdown cell

Tags: markdown, jupyter

`t.test(Boston$medv)`.*Hint: You can approximate a 95% confidence interval using the formula $[\hat{\mu}-2 S E(\hat{\mu}), \hat{\mu}+2 S E(\hat{\mu})]$.*

In Jupyter markdown cell, the $ in the `t.test(Boston$medv)` conflicts with the Latex formula. After running this markdown cell, the Italic, i.e. *Hint:...*, didn't display correctly. How to correct this syntax error in this markdown cell?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have another dollar sign somewhere? It displays fine on my side. The only time it does not display correctly is when the code quotes (i.e. \`) are missing.

Comment: Yes.In my Jupyter markdowncell, the Italic didn't display well, and the * before   and after hint  were displayed as _( i.e.  _Hint:...)